# SQL: Accumulative columns & Sum Across the Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table and its record:

```
Profile | Level | CHgt | BHgt | SHgt | Z
ABCD1   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 50   | 0
ABCD1   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 0
ABCD1   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 0
ABCD2   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 60   | 0
ABCD2   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 80   | 0
ABCD2   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 80   | 0
ABCD3   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 40   | 0
ABCD3   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 60   | 0
ABCD3   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 60   | 0
ABCD1   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 50   | 0
ABCD1   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 0
ABCD1   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 0
```

I want to calculate the Z, but I need to create two more variables (BHgt2, SHgt2: can be created in the back end of calculation)

```
Profile | Level | CHgt | BHgt | SHgt | BHgt2 | SHgt2 | Z
ABCD1   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 50   | 11    | 0     | 26
ABCD1   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 22    | 120   | 157
ABCD1   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 33    | 190   | 238
ABCD2   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 60   | 11    | 0     | 26
ABCD2   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 80   | 22    | 140   | 177
ABCD2   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 80   | 33    | 220   | 268
ABCD3   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 40   | 11    | 0     | 26
ABCD3   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 60   | 22    | 100   | 137
ABCD3   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 60   | 33    | 170   | 218
ABCD1   | 1     | 15   | 11   | 50   | 11    | 0     | 26
ABCD1   | 2     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 22    | 120   | 157
ABCD1   | 3     | 15   | 11   | 70   | 33    | 190   | 238
```

Essentially BHgt2 is accumulative by Profile and Level & SHgt2 is accumulative of its value + previous value, however, level 1 = 0 and finally Z = CHgt + BHgt2+SHgt2

I have tried using ROW_Number & joins and combination of with cte; but my mind seems to be stuck.

If one single select statement won't be possible, perhaps first update queries for BHgt2 and SHgt2

then Select Query to calculate the Z

Anyone have an idea for a select statement? this is for SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two items:
1) Gordon's response was virtually spot on except for the Level=0. Should be Level=1

2) I'm not convinced the last row of your desired results is correct, I think you are off by 10.   **If I am not correct, let me know and I will re-visit this.**

```
Declare @Table table (Profile varchar(25),Level int,CHgt int,BHgt int, SHgt int, Z int)
Insert into @Table values
('ABCD1' , 1  , 15 , 11 , 50 , 0),
('ABCD1' , 2  , 15 , 11 , 70 , 0),
('ABCD1' , 3  , 15 , 11 , 70 , 0),
('ABCD2' , 1  , 15 , 11 , 60 , 0),
('ABCD2' , 2  , 15 , 11 , 80 , 0),
('ABCD2' , 3  , 15 , 11 , 80 , 0),
('ABCD3' , 1  , 15 , 11 , 40 , 0),
('ABCD3' , 2  , 15 , 11 , 60 , 0),
('ABCD3' , 3  , 15 , 11 , 60 , 0)

select A.Profile
      ,A.Level
      ,A.CHgt
      ,A.BHgt
      ,A.SHgt
      ,B.Bhgt2
      ,Shgt2 = case when Level = 1 then 0 else SHgt2 end
      ,Z     = CHgt + B.Bhgt2 + case when level = 1 then 0 else SHgt2 end 
From @Table A 
Cross Apply (Select Bhgt2 = sum(Bhgt)
                   ,SHgt2 = sum(SHgt)
              From  @Table B
              Where B.Profile = A.Profile and A.Level >= B.Level 
            ) B;
```

Returns

```
Profile Level   CHgt    BHgt    SHgt    Bhgt2   Shgt2   Z
ABCD1   1       15      11      50      11      0       26
ABCD1   2       15      11      70      22      120     157
ABCD1   3       15      11      70      33      190     238
ABCD2   1       15      11      60      11      0       26
ABCD2   2       15      11      80      22      140     177
ABCD2   3       15      11      80      33      220     268
ABCD3   1       15      11      40      11      0       26
ABCD3   2       15      11      60      22      100     137
ABCD3   3       15      11      60      33      160     208
```

Comment: Let me try this, and btw your output seems right than the one I typed

Comment: Every columns seems fine, but i'm not getting the right # for Bhgt2

Comment: @DavidChen My results match your desired results except for the 10 in the last row.

Comment: I just edited my question, what happened if I were to duplicate the ABCD1, will your solution produce same result?

Comment: @David: Changing the requirements of your question the way you just did is not very nice.  If this post answered your (original) question correctly, then just accept it to show some appreciation. If you have another question, then ask another question.

Comment: @DavidChen I don't understand or see your duplicate of ABCD1

Comment: @DavidChen Two items.  1) I agree with sstan's comment.  It was a little insulting.  2) The duplication of ABCD1 without an IDENTITY or some other sequence is a poor structure.  There is no way you could apply an update to ABCD1 without impacting at least two records.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier in more recent versions of SQL Server.  But you can do this using `apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.Bhgt2,
       (case when level = 0 then 0 else SHgt2 end) as Shgt2,
       (CHgt + t2.Bhgt2 + (case when level = 0 then 0 else SHgt2 end) ) as Z
from t cross apply
     (select sum(Bhgt) as Bhgt2,
             sum(SHgt) as SHgt2
      from t t2
      where t2.profile = t.profile and t2.level <= t.level 
     ) t2;
```